# How to apply the same style to different columns of the attributes table?

Tags: qgis

How do I apply the same Categorized style, including same custom intervals  and respective labels,  to more than one column, if I have a shapefile with an extensive attributes table? If I save a style for a column, I can’t apply it to another one.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be a bug in QGIS 1.8, because in QGIS 1.74 it applies the same user defined intervals for any chosen variable. However, before I have discovered this, I’ve found a solution: I would save all my custom information into a style (intervals, labels) in Graduated renderer, then open the style file externally into notepad, change the name of the variable by hand and save a new style. I ended up with a style file for every column I needed mapped. Not elegant at all, but it did the trick and I needed it fast.

Answer (score 3):

Use the rule based renderer, specifically using the "refine current rules" option.